# Fast replica in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

As I am a newbie to `Cassandra`, I was confused with this term known as '`fast replica`'. Basically what I know is `dynamic snitch` identifies the faster replica during the reading process and data from the faster replica is compared with the other replicas with the help of hash(for every message) and if the data is consistent then data from the `fast replica` is sent to the client or replicas go under the read repair(if the read consistency level is not met). What does exactly '`fast replica`' means? Does it mean the read query doesn't need to query other nodes for the data? Please guide me through it. I couldn't find any relevant SO posts for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra uses phi accural failure detection alogrithm to identify the node's health. A dynamic snitch that sorts endpoints by latency with an adapted phi failure detector.

> What does exactly 'fast replica' means?

The replica which is the top scorer in terms of latency and proximity.

> Does it mean the read query doesn't need to query other nodes for the
>   data?

As the score of replicas keep on changing dynamically and hence the fastest replica will keep on getting data request until it is not the top scorer anymore which makes sense.

For more details you can check the code [FD](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/FailureDetector.java) and [DS](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/locator/DynamicEndpointSnitch.java)

Comment: So in simpler terms can I say like this that fast replica is the one who has much better health( with the help of PHI ) than the other nodes ?

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Laxmikant for better clarity.